# R: x and y lengths differ with function

Tags: r, function, vector, plot

I'm pretty new in R. Currently trying to write a function that takes a path, a variable name and a variable label, and turn it into a plot.

Code:

```
plot_var <- function(dirpath,parname,parnamequotes) {
  mydata <- read.csv(dirpath, skip=6)
  par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  plot(mydata$parname, mydata$trust_coop_total, xlab = parnamequotes, ylab = "trust_coop", main = "Sensitivity of max_trust", pch=16, col = rgb(0,191,255,50, maxColorValue = 255))
  }
plot_var("XXXX.csv", max_trust, "max_trust")
```

I keep getting this error: 
`Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

However, I believe that the independent and dependent variables are the same length. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `dput()`to provide us your data. Then it will be much easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

- `mydata[, parnamequotes]` (return a vector) or,
- `mydata[[parnamequotes]]` (return a vector) or,
- `mydata[parnamequotes]` (return a data frame)

in place of `mydata$parname` (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-vector-of-column-names)) and remove `parname` from the function.

```
plot_var <- function(dirpath,parnamequotes) {
  mydata <- read.csv(dirpath, skip=6)
  par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  plot(mydata[, parnamequotes], 
       mydata$trust_coop_total, 
       xlab = parnamequotes, ylab = "trust_coop", 
       main = "Sensitivity of max_trust", 
       pch=16, col = rgb(0,191,255,50, maxColorValue = 255))
  }

plot_var("XXXX.csv", "max_trust")
```

Comment: great, thanks! Beginners question: when to use $ and when [,] ?

Comment: You are welcome. You cannot use $ with variable. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-vector-of-column-names